# Create checkboxlist out of data model and store it back in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Step
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class StepDate
{
    public int StepId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class CreateProjectVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Steps> Steps { get; set; }
    public List<StepDate> StepDates { get; set; }
}
```

I have the given data model. First, I want to create a page with a checkboxlist for each Step with additional input fields for StartDate and EndDate. Second, on post I want to store the Steps and according Dates that are checked. CRUD-functions for data models are already implemented. I only need the way to communicate between cshtml and cs.

Comment: "First, I want to create a page with a checkboxlist for each Step with additional input fields for StartDate and EndDate. Second, on post I want to store the Steps and according Dates that are checked. CRUD-functions for data models are already implemented. I only need the way to communicate between cshtml and cs." Please provide what have you tried?

Comment: Have the model inside the cshtml. I was able to create a form with checkpoints named to the steps and the other fileds (name, description, startdate, enddate) but i don't know how to create/bind them to get the input data into the model. When I make a post, I only see the strings inside the model, but not the data of the checkpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo with ajax:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestCreateProjectVM()
        {
            //Step[i] is related to StepData[i]
            CreateProjectVM c = new CreateProjectVM { Description = "d", Name = "c" };
            List<StepDate> StepDates = new List<StepDate> { new StepDate { ProjectId = 1, Selected = false, StepId = 11, StartDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 2) }, new StepDate { ProjectId = 1, Selected = false, StepId = 12, StartDate = new DateTime(2012, 2, 1), EndDate = new DateTime(2012, 2, 2) } };
            List<Step> Steps = new List<Step> { new Step { Id = 11, Name = "step1" }, new Step { Id = 12, Name = "step2" } };
            c.StepDates = StepDates;
            c.Steps = Steps;
            return View(c);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TestCreateProjectVM(CreateProjectVM createProjectVM)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

View:

```
  Name:<input asp-for="Name" />
    Description:<input asp-for="Description" />
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.StepDates.Count(); i++)
    {
<div id="@i">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label asp-for="@Model.StepDates[i].Selected">
            <input asp-for="@Model.StepDates[i].Selected" />
        </label>
    </div>


    <label asp-for="@Model.Steps[i].Name"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.StepDates[i].StartDate" />
    <input asp-for="@Model.StepDates[i].EndDate" />
    <input asp-for="@Model.Steps[i].Id" hidden />
    <input asp-for="@Model.Steps[i].Name" hidden />
    <input asp-for="@Model.StepDates[i].StepId" hidden />
    <input asp-for="@Model.StepDates[i].ProjectId" hidden />

</div>
    }
    <button  onclick="submit()">submit</button>

@section scripts{
    <script>
    function submit() {
        var model = {};
        model.Name = $("#Name").val();
        model.Description = $("#Description").val();
        var StepDates = new Array();
        var Steps = new Array();
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            var stepDate = {};
            stepDate.Selected = true;
            stepDate.StartDate = $('#' + $(this).attr("id").replace("Selected", "StartDate")).val();
            stepDate.EndDate = $('#' + $(this).attr("id").replace("Selected", "EndDate")).val();
            stepDate.StepId = $('#' + $(this).attr("id").replace("Selected", "StepId")).val();
            stepDate.ProjectId = $('#' + $(this).attr("id").replace("Selected", "ProjectId")).val();
            StepDates.push(stepDate);
            var step = {};
            step.Name = $('#' + $(this).attr("id").replace("Selected", "Name").replace("StepDates", "Steps")).val();
            step.Id = $('#' + $(this).attr("id").replace("Selected", "Id").replace("StepDates", "Steps")).val();
            Steps.push(step);
        })
        model.StepDates = StepDates;
        model.Steps = Steps;
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("TestCreateProjectVM", "Test1")',
            data: model
             }).done(function (data) {

    });
    }
    </script>
    
}
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Thx for this fast and great response! I wonder, do I have to use the script part because of the existing ViewModel I'm using, or is it just the best way for this kind of task? So far I used SelectListItems in other ViewModels directly for Dropdownlists and converted the data from the database in the code section before I return the model, but the data model I got before were nearly the same like a collection SelectlistItems

Comment: If you want to pass all the steps and stapdates,you only need to use form post.If you need to pass only selected data,you need to  use js,so that you can choose the data you want to pass.

Comment: ah sorry, I've haven't had the time to explore this solution more specific. I think the first tries failed because I used an foreach. In this case I didn't get the data inside the model.